# Inheritance in selenium webdriver using testng

Tags: java, inheritance, selenium

```
package user;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class Login {

    public WebDriver driver;

  @Test

  public void Signin() throws Exception   {

      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.navigate().refresh();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='header']/div/div/ul/li[6]/a")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
      driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123456");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[5]/td[2]/input")).click();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
    }


  @BeforeTest

  public void BeforeTest() {

     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.get("http://test.com/");
  }
```

INHERITANCE

```
package user;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class Addtocart extends Login {


    public WebDriver driver;

  @Test

  public void Cart() throws Exception {

      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/div/a")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/Catalog/Featured')]")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("//div[4]/div/a/img")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("anchorAddToWishList")).click();*/
  }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

      Addtocart ac = new Addtocart();
      ac.BeforeMethod();
          ac.Signin();
      ac.Cart();
  }
}
```

When i try to call the super class method first. the sub class method is calling first. How to call super class method initially

Comment: In Testng.xml include this  <suite name = "Test Suite" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
 <test name = "Regression Test Suite">
  <classes>
   <class name = "Login"/>
   <class name = "AddtoCart"/>
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>

Answer (score 0):

With TestNG Try use:

```
@Test(priority=1) (assign the position to execute)
```

Answer (score 0):

you never defined 'BeforeMethod' method in your super class, just a observation.

**TestNG** - Number 0 has the highest priority(it’ll be executed first) and the priority goes on based on the given number i.e., 0 has the highest priority than 1. 1 has the highest priority than 2 and so on.

public class TestNG_Priority_Annotations {

```
@Test(priority=6)
public void c_method(){
System.out.println("I'm in method C");
}
@Test(priority=9)
public void b_method(){
System.out.println("I'm in method B");
}
@Test(priority=1)
public void a_method(){
System.out.println("I'm in method A");
}
@Test(priority=0)
public void e_method(){
System.out.println("I'm in method E");
}
@Test(priority=3)
public void d_method(){
System.out.println("I'm in method D");
}
```

}

**Output will be:**

I'm in method E

I'm in method A

I'm in method D

I'm in method C

I'm in method B